# Typescript: type determination based on property value

Tags: typescript

I was pretty sure Typescript was able to determine an extended class based on a property value, e.g.:

```
interface Base {
    type: string;
    child?: Base;
}

interface Ext extends Base {
    type: 'test';
    sth: string;
}

z({
    type: 'a',
    child: {
        type: 'b',
    }
}); // ok

z({
    type: 'a',
    child: {
        type: 'test',
        sth: 'val'
    }
}); // not ok

function z(input: Base) { }
```

Above example doesn't work, TS tells me property `sth` doesn't exist on interface `Base`. What do I need to change so that TS will understand the child to actually be type of `Ext`, because of the value `'test'` on the `type` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out:

```
interface Base {
    child?: Ext;
}

interface Ext1 extends Base {
    type: 'a';
}
interface Ext2 extends Base {
    type: 'test';
    sth: string;
}

type Ext = Ext1 | Ext2;

z({
    type: 'a',
    child: {
        type: 'test',
        sth: 'x'
    }
});

function z(input: Ext) { }
```

This example will fail if `sth` is not defined while `type` is `'test'` instead of the other way around

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare it as type `Ext` and it should pass

```
let x: Ext = {
    type: 'test',
    sth: 'value'
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't TS be able to figure out it must be `Ext` already, because `Ext` extends `Base` but makes a clear distinction based on the value of `type`?

Comment: the type of Ext is still Base (so that will work) but yet it contains keys that do not exist in the base interface.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes from [excess property check](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks), which is done only when variable is initialized with object literal. To avoid it, you need to initialize the value with something which is not an object literal, for example you can add intermediate variable

```
let o = {
    type: 'test',
    sth: 'value'
}
let x1: Base = o;
```

or you can add a type assertion

```
let x2: Base = {
    type: 'test',
    sth: 'value'
} as Base;
```

Another solution is to make `Base` and `z` generic, parameterized on the type of `Child` which should be a subtype of `Base` (note that self-referential type constraints are tricky to get right, but it seems to work in this case, the minor issue is with default value for `Base` which causes `Base` in the constraint to be inferred as `Child extends Base<{ type: string; child?: Base<any> | undefined; }` - `any` here could be problematic but does not seem to affect anything in the example).

```
interface Base<Child extends Base = { type: string, child?: Base }> {
    type: string;
    child?: Child;
}

interface Ext extends Base {
    type: 'test';
    sth: string;
}

z({
    type: 'a',
    child: {
        type: 'b',
    }
}); // ok

z({
    type: 'a',
    child: {
        type: 'test',
        sth: 'val'
    }
}); // not ok

function z<B extends Base>(input: B) { }
```

Comment: Both would work, but I'm pretty sure I once saw an example of how TS can figure this out by itself.